# Artifactory disk space usage much higher than reported repository size

Tags: disk-space-utilization, artifactory

Our artifactory installation has 500GB data disk allocated to it.  Yesterday it ran out of space and went about cleaning up old artifacts (something I thought was being done automatically but it wasn't).  After deleting over 200GB worth of old artifacts, I could see trash can size reported as 228 GB. I then emptied the trash can and manually forced the garbage collection run. I also manually ran "Prune unreferenced data".  Now I'm trying to understand why the actual space on the disk is not being freed up.  Artifactory now reports the following:

[image]

How can I free up the 200+ GB of disk space that shouldn't be used any more?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue recently. It turned out that Artifacotry 6.12 introduced a [new GC strategy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Regular+Maintenance+Operations#RegularMaintenanceOperations-GarbageCollection). From the same document:

> Unreferenced binaries, (including existing unreferenced binaries or artifacts that were manually deleted from the trashcan), will be deleted during the previous Full GC strategy that runs every 20 GC iterations (configurable, 'artifactory.gc.skipFullGcBetweenMinorIterations=20').

This means that by default, after deleting an artifact from the UI or using the REST API, the actual files will be removed from the filestore only after 20 runs of the Garbage Collector. So you could just wait for 20/(24/4) = 3.33 days if the GC runs every 4 hours which is the default. This only takes place if the artifacts are unreferenced, meaning that they are not used by any other repository.

Or, you could also run GC 20 times either via the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RunGarbageCollection) or manually via the Admin panel to enforce a full GC.